# html element overflow screen and showing blank spaces

Tags: html, css

My page looks like this:
[image]

there are black blank spaces below the actual content, and the html root is showing overflow on the devmode, how can i fix this? i have to height 100% tried: changing the html in index.css to `height: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

Can i see your full code? But it's maybe you dont set the margin in the root

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, it seems as if the class `lg:px-[10%]` may be the culprit; this appears to be creating a 10% padding around the element. Try removing that and see what happens.